# What are ORM patterns other than Active Record and Data Mapper?

Tags: php, design-patterns, data-access-layer

I've been reading about DAL design and ORMs in PHP and so far I've come across "Active Record" and "Data Mapper".

Are these two the only patterns available or are there more patterns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about being PHP-specific, but the key design patterns I've used to create ORM functionality, and key patterns I see in well-established ORMs are:

- [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)
- [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html)
- [Lazy Load](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html)
- [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are different Object-Relational patterns, every one is in a different layer,
Architectural, Behavioral, Structural or Metadata Mapping, you can see more
details here http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html